# jQuery set ancestor element for scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where all my selectors all have the same ancestor element

```
$('#foo .bar')...
$('#foo .some_class')...
$('#foo .some_other_class')...
```

I was wondering if there was a way to tell jQuery to always assume the selector will descend from `#foo`? So something like

```
$.ancestorWillAlwaysBe('#foo');
$('.bar')...
$('.some_class')...
$('.some_other_class')...
```

Comment: guessing that this is an over simplification of issue, what is higher level situation in your code...if in a handler `this` might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are lazy to type all those `#foo`. Here's a way to do that in a simpler way:

```
var e = $("#foo");  //short enough
$('.bar', e);
$('.some_class', e);
$('.some_other_class', e);
```

Or if you ***really*** that lazy, you can do this:

```
$ = function(que, anc){
    if($.ancestor){
        return jQuery(que, $.ancestor);
    }else{
        return jQuery(que, anc);
    }
}

$.ancestor = "#foo";  //Ancestor will now always be #foo
$('.bar')...
$('.some_class')...
$('.some_other_class')...
$.ancestor = undefined;  //Clear
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/agnHy/

Comment: you know how to use jquery, so you must be *extremely* lazy. :) otherwise you would just write native javascript like a real man.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ancestor = $("#foo");
$$ = function(arg) {
    return $(arg, $ancestor);
}

$$('.bar').html("descendant of foo");
```

personally I would just use something like `$ancestor.find('.bar')` though...for code clarity reasons.

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple way to do exactly what you ask, but you can find it:

```
var $foo = $('#foo');
```

And then:

```
var others = $foo.find('.bar');
```

Remember that when possible it's a good idea to use tag names on the rightmost part of the selector (though nowadays selector interpretation in modern browsers is so fast that optimizations are not often worth the trouble). Thus:

```
var others = $foo.find('span.bar');
```

Of course sometimes that's not desirable, if for example you really can't easily narrow down the element types involved.

*edit* — the convention of giving a cached jQuery result a name starting with "$" is just that: a convention. It's not necessary and I sympathize with those who find it distasteful :-)

Comment: Would it be better to use the context instead of find? $('span.bar', $foo)

Comment: @v0idless: context implements `find()` internally anyway, so it makes no difference.

Comment: @v0idless the context (2 argument) version of the jQuery call is (for reasons I can't recall) frowned on by the jQuery guys.  They seem to prefer using `.find()` explicitly.

Comment: `find()` is faster than any other methods for same purpose. I've tested it on jsperf some time ago.

Comment: @Derek that's what people are saying shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Pointy - Why not? Inside `$()` is faster than `.find()` http://jsperf.com/or-find (1% faster, google chrome)

Comment: @Derek no, the 2-argument form is always evaluated inside jQuery with a call to `.find()` anyway. That won't be significantly slower, but it can't be faster. When I ran the jsperf, the `.find` was very slightly faster but the difference is going to be way less than measuring accuracy.

Comment: @Pointy - You are right. Looks like `.find` is *little* faster when I put more elements inside.

Comment: Just to confirm others' comments, [`find()` is, *marginally*, faster](http://jsperf.com/using-find-versus-context-in-jquery).

Answer (score 3):

I'm  a bit lazy and would probably just create a function:

```
function a(elem) {
    return $('#foo').find(elem);
}
```

and use it like so:

```
a('.bar').css('color', 'red');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7S5nc/)

Or just create an expression to weed out anything not inside #foo since that is probably what you are after, otherwise just targeting the class would do just fine

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {  
    foo: function(elem){  
         return $(elem).closest('#foo').length;  
    }  
});
```

And do:

```
$('.bar:foo').css('color', 'red');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7S5nc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for either

`Child Selector (“parent > child”)`

Which selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent"

OR

`:first-child Selector`

Which selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.